# Ctrl+D equivalent in DBeaver

Tags: dbeaver

I checked the DBeaver shortcuts docs page and Googled a lot but couldn't find any info on this...

Does **DBeaver** have a **`Ctrl+D` equivalent** (I am referring to `Ctrl+D` in VS Code, where it multi-selects by adding the current selection)?

**Background**
*I work with BigQuery a lot, and in BigQuery Console and VS Code they both have the Ctrl+D functionality but not in DBeaver (at least not by default with the same hotkey)*

Answer (score 9):

DBeaver does not come with this functionality working by default, but you can very easily add this shortcut yourself with the following 4 steps:

1. On the top context menu, click `Window -> Preferences`. Then select `User Interface -> Keys`.
2. The command you want to add a binding to is the `Multi selection down relative to anchor selection`. So, on the filter text box, write `multi`. Select it, then on the bottom pane select the `Binding` text box, and press the shortcut keys down (In this case, press `Ctrl+D`).
   Make sure that the `When` column changes to `Editing Text`. Otherwise, change this yourself. It will look like the iamge below [image: DBeaver key preferences example]
3. The `Ctrl+D` shortcut is already taken by the "Delete Line" command, so you need to unbind them. On the filter textbox, write `ctrl+d`. Then click on row that shows `Delete Line`, and click the `Unbind Command` button.
4. Click `Apply and Close` and have fun.

Comment: I don't see multi selection at all. Is this a possible version issue?

Comment: @user8491363 Possibly... Currently I'm using DBeaver 22.3.4 (the most recent version), and the multi selection is still there.

Comment: I would also add ESC binding to "End multi-selection" because I also use that in VS Code a lot.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that, if you are in multi-selection mode, and you ctrl+v something, it might paste it multiple times for each selection, which is probably not what you want. I'm still not sure how to properly deal with that, though... I just end up writing the stuff manually instead of pasting.

Answer (score -1):

I believe it is Ctrl+Alt+Down (from https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Shortcuts/)